# how to declare multiple session variables according to the length of PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

```
session_start();
$imgList = $_REQUEST['imgList']; //comes through post (jquery)
$i = 0;
$a = explode(',', $imgList); 
$abc = count($a);

for ($e = 0; $e < $abc; $e++)
{
  echo $_SESSION['c+$i']=$a[$e];
  $i++;
}

echo $_SESSION['c+$i']; //this returns the last value
echo count($_SESSION['c+$i']); //returns only length 1
echo count($i); // returns only length 1
```

I don't know why more than one variable are not initilizing. can anyone please tell me about htis problem or fix this.i"ll be very thankful to you for this favor

Comment: What is the value of `$_REQUEST['imgList']`/`$a`?

Comment: You are using single quotes in your `$SESSION` array key, hence, it will always literally be `c+$i`, no matter what value `$i` has. I suggest you read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

Comment: $("#check").click(function(){

      var data = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
      return this.value;
       }).get();
        var dataString = "imgList="+ data;
       $.post('filter.php',dataString,function(theResponse){
    alert(theResponse);

Comment: @roberto06 i did it but its not showing any result and givin an error

Comment: `$_SESSION[]` is an array. Read more about [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and how to use them. Also read about [strings](http://php.net/language.types.string). The section about [single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) could help you understand half of your mistakes in the posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code completely like below:-

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
$imgList = $_REQUEST['imgList']; //comes through post (jquery)
$a = explode(',', $imgList); 
$_SESSION['c'][] = $a;
print_r($_SESSION['c']);
```

Now on other page if you need to access this SESSION data, do like below:-

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['c']);
foreach($_SESSION['c'] as arr){
  echo $arr."\n";
}
```

Comment: @aqib  i have changed code completely.check now.it is more easy solution

Comment: thank you so much for your help.may God bless you. sure!

Comment: @aqib  glad to help you :)

Comment: :-) see you again

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $_SESSION['c+$i']=$a[$e];
```

please use "c+$i" instead of 'c+$i'.

Comment: when i echo count($_SESSION["c+$i"]); this turn undefiend index

Comment: Of course it show underfiend,$i is a variable，after loop,the c+$i is more 1 than the last index. remove all echo count()...，and use var_dump($_SESSION)，you can get all.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you are using single quotes in your `$SESSION` array key, hence, it will always literally be `c+$i`, no matter what value $i has.

You need to use either double quotes :

```
$_SESSION["c+$i"]=$a[$e];
```

Or the PHP concatenating operator :

```
$_SESSION['c+' . $i] = $a[$e];
```

BTW, there's no need for an `echo` there, as there's no need for a `$i` variable, since `$e` already ranges from 0 to `$abc` and is equal to `$i` in each `for` iteration.

Also, `count($i)` will always return `1` , since `$i` is an int.

Comment: i want to use these session variables on other page that is why usin $_SESSION["c+$i"]=$a[$e];

Comment: but how can i use these variables on other page?

Comment: I wouldn't use `c+$i`, I would build an array inside `$_SESSION['c']`, by using `$_SESSION['c'][$i]`. This way, `$_SESSION['c']` will contain all your values, you'll just have to loop through it to retrieve the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();

// More important evalutate vars to avoid log errors en your server
if( isset( $_REQUEST['imgList'] ) && !empty( $_REQUEST['imgList'] ) )
{
    // $imgList = $_REQUEST['imgList']; remove, make direct,
    // $i = 0; remove, optimize recourses, 
    $a = explode(',', trim( $_REQUEST['imgList'], "," ) );  // trim to remove empty positions in array
    // $abc = count($a); remove, optimize recourses, free memory

    for ($e = 0; $e < count( $a ); $e++)
    {
        $_SESSION[ "c_".$e ] = $a[ $e ]; // remove echo, "+" what is ?? separator?? if it is, change by underscope
    }   
    // echo $_SESSION["c_0"]; // 0,1,2 at length $a -1
    // echo count($_SESSION['c+$i']); // you count string ??? or array???, I don't understand this
    // echo count($i); // returns only length 1 // count a one number????, I don't understand this

    // to print
    for ($e = 0; $e < count( $a ); $e++)
    {
        echo $_SESSION[ "c_".$e ]; // print value of session in position $e
    }

    echo count( $e ); // Number of vars sesions created!

    // to remove
    for ($e = 0; $e < count( $a ); $e++)
    {
        unset( $_SESSION[ "c_".$e ] ); // remove var session in position $e
    }
}
```